# Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, heap-memory

I am getting ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit allocation error while running my angular application. I have tried reinstalling nodejs and npm.

I tried increase size by using command `node --max-old-space-size=8192`

I am on a Windows 10 system. RAM: 8gb

npm: '6.4.1'
Angular CLI: 7.3.6
Node: 10.15.3
Angular: 7.2.10

Comment: how did you solve it?